# looking for alternitive to passing an associative array in JSP

Tags: java, forms, jsp

I'm using JSP where the user selects a background. The number of times each past selection has been made will be recorded. Example: green was used twice, yellow was used once, red was used five times. I wanted to use an associative array where the colour is the key and the value is the number of times it was used. But Java doesn't have associative arrays so I guess my next best option is a normal array?

Also, how do I pass this information from one page to the next? I was thinking of using hidden fields but that wouldn't work with an array.

Comment: I might be wide of the mark here, have you looked at using something like a jquery-ui theme http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bozho said, use a `HashMap<Color, Integer>`. For updating the count you'd have to get the integer from the map, increment and put it back to the map.

> Also, how do I pass this information from one page to the next?

You might store that map in the user's session.

Answer (score 0):

Java has [`HashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), which is exactly an associative array - you have a key of any type (may be string) and a value of any type, with lookup O(1)